# How to visualize CIFAR10 images as matrices

Tags: tensorflow, slice, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to work with CIFAR10 images. I have the following snippet

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets,layers,models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels)=datasets.cifar10.load_data()
#train_images,test_images=train_images/,test_images
```

when I print  `print(train_images[0])` I get 32*32*3 matrix, when I print `print(train_images[0][0)` I get 32*3 matrix, however I  thought it should be 32*32 matrix. How does slicing work with this image, which dimension come first. Any insight and recommendation on reading material will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

train_images variable have batch of images and images are numpy metrics and slicing works same for all metrics in numpy.

Dimensions comes as [batch, rows, columns, channels].

To get first image you will print: `print(train_images[0].shape)` and it will output (32, 32, 3).

To get first channel of image you will print: `print(train_images[0, :, :, 0])` and it will output (32, 32) first channel and so on `print(train_images[0, :, :, 1])` for second channel, `print(train_images[0, :, :, 2])` for third channel.
Where ':' implies all values.

`train_images[0, 0]` will output values from first row of first image from batch (32, 3)

More on: [basics indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html),[arrays indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: This has given me a perfect insight